# "Protocol mismatch" when trying to access tunneled HTTP port

Tags: ssh, http, ssh-tunnel

I'm using Mac 10.7.4 and I have an HTTP service running on port 8082 of a remote server, which I can only access through an intermediate server.  So I execute these tunnel commands

```
ssh -L 8082:remote-server:22 dalvarado@intermediate-server
ssh dalvarado@localhost -p 8082
```

However, when I open a web browser (either Safari or Chrome) and visit

```
http://localhost:8082/
```

I get the error

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Protocol mismatch.
```

I have verified that the remote-server's sshd_config file contains "Protocol 2" and I even tried adding the "-2" flag to the above SSH commands, but I'm still getting the error.

Any help is appreciated, - Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a single tunnel, provided that the intermediate server's settings allow this:

```
ssh -L 8082:remote-server:8082 dalvarado@intermediate-server
```

Then point your browser to

```
http://localhost:8082/
```

If remote-server:8082 is only accessible from remote-server itself, you need to tunnel further:

```
ssh -L 8022:remote-server:22 dalvarado@intermediate-server
ssh -L 8082:localhost:8082 dalvarado@localhost -p 8022
```

Then point your browser to `http://localhost:8082/`

Comment: I tried running your SSH command but then visiting the URL produces the error, "No data received".  I know there is a web page there because when I execute "wget http://localhost:8082/" on the remote-server, I get an index.html page.

Comment: What happens if you ssh to the intermediate server, and then from there execute "wget remote-server:8082" ?

Comment: I get a "Connection to remote-server failed: Connection timed out" message

Comment: I have edited my original answer with a possible solution

Comment: You have tried 
`ssh -L 8082:remote-server:22 dalvarado@intermediate-server`
So a connection to localhost:8082 is forwarded to the port 22 (SSH service) of the remote server. It is not what you want since you obviously wants to access a HTTP service.
Try 
`ssh -L 8082:remote-server:80 dalvarado@intermediate-server` instead