# What command should be used to connect via SSH through squid proxy?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, proxy, squid, putty

I have set up a Squid HTTP Proxy (in centOS) and intended to use it also for ssh connections.

Managed to configure putty (in a windows client) to use this proxy while connecting by ssh. Confirmed in the "target host" that the ssh connection was coming from Proxy server ip instead of the windows client IP.

Used:

- targethost: 22 for ssh
- proxyserv: 3128 for proxy (along with proxy credentials)

I'm now having problems connecting to the "target host" using Ubuntu and the same proxy server.

I have tried the following:

```
me@mycomp:~$ connect-proxy -H test@proxyserv:3128 targethost 22
Enter proxy authentication password for test@proxyserv: 
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6
```

It hangs in last line, expecting some input. All attempts resulted in a "Protocol mismatch." error.

Putty successfully connects to the http proxy and sends credentials, showing me ssh login right away.
- How to do (with commands in Ubuntu) the same putty does?
- Is there any other way than connect-proxy command to do this?

Edit: Also tried the following with same result ("Protocol mismatch")

```
me@mycomp:~$ connect-proxy -H test@proxyserv:3128 targethost 22 ssh -l myshel_login
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit: Solution details** (thanks to NickW pointing the right way)

### installed corkscrew and added to ssh_config

```
Host targethost   
    ProxyCommand corkscrew proxyserv 3128 %h %p /etc/ssh/proxypass
```

### created proxypass file

```
login:password
```

### Restarted ssh and used a simple ssh command

```
ssh mylogin@targethost
```

(ssh password was asked as usual)

Comment: maybe this will help?  http://serverfault.com/questions/420875/protocol-mismatch-when-trying-to-access-tunneled-http-port

Comment: Thanks, I have Checked. In that case, the goal is to access HTTP. As I have a proxy I don't need tunneling, just browser definitions for that.I do need to access SSH (over the proxy), but looks like it expects a HTTP request. Putty successfully "informs" squid we want SSH, and I get shell access over the proxy, but I can't do this with commands. [Edited question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to add [corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) to your Ubuntu box, and add this line:

> ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy.work.com 80 %h %p

to your .ssh/config file.

Comment: Thanks NickW. Not so straightforward for other employees to configure as a command, but does the trick perfectly. Edited question with details on my implementation hoping it helps someone. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance!